# Git: Mix a feature branch with a local configuration branch

Tags: git, github

I’m working on an open source project and I’d like to contribute my changes back to it. I have two environments where I’d like to work on it. The first is its upstream environment the other is my production environment. My current approach is to keep two separate branches; a feature branches with the changes I want to push back to the upstream and a local configuration branch where I house changes I need to adapt the software to my production configuration. The feature branch will have many commits, but the configuration branch will have only one commit.

My question is how do I switch back and forth between environments. I need to do the development with the feature branch and local configuration branch in place, but when I push back to the upstream I don’t want the commit from the local configuration branch. I also don’t want to pollute my submission to the upstream with a revert.

Another way to ask is graphically. Given the picture below, I want to work on the code with c1+f1..fN in place, but when I create a pull request, I don't want c1 to be part of the pull request. I don't want c1 + a revert of c1 in either.

[image: a commit tree]

Comment: What do you mean by "upstream environment" and "production environment"?

Comment: And what exactly does the "local configuration branch" contain? Can you give an example?

Comment: @sleske I added a picture that hopefully explains what I want better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have historically handled this by simply rewriting history to remove the configuration commit when I go to merge the feature branch upstream. Consider this:

```
S                     (starting point, whichever branch you're working off of)
S - A                 ('config' branch)
S - A - B - C - D - E ('feature' branch, based off 'config')
```

Assuming you're careful that none of your changes conflict with the changes made in `A`, you can run:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i {upstream remote}/{upstream branch}
```

and remove `A` from the history before going to merge your changes upstream.

This leaves you with:

```
S - B' - C' - D' - E'
```

which should make for a clean pull request into the upstream repository.

That said, different teams have different tolerances for history rewriting. If you're working alone, though, it should have a very minimal impact.

Comment: Thanks for point me at this -- looks like the perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is no really nice way to solve this with git (or any VCS for that matter).

The best solution with git is to remove the commits before pushing, as  joshtkling explains in his answer.

However, there are some disadvantages:

- You must be careful not to have "feature" commits that depend on "config" commits, otherwise you'll get conflicts when removing the config commits, which can get messy.
- You must remember to remove the config commits each time you push; there is a risk of accidentally pushing too much (maybe even stuff like passwords in the config commits?).
- After pushing, you must reintroduce your "config" commits, until your push is accepted upstream.
- Finally, if you want to work with multiple branches locally, merging between them will be difficult, because of the rebasing you had to do above.

So in short, it will work in simple cases, but can become painful.

My advice: **Try to change the application so you do not need "config" commits.**

Make whatever you need to change configurable, so you do not need to change code. IMHO it's a bad sign if you need to change code (or other parts supplied by upstream) to adapt a software to your environment - so your changes will probably help others, too.